# What does a $ symbol mean in a JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

First of all, please bare my ignorance. This may be a very basic question. But I am not to find it out.

I see some thing like this in the code. I dont understand what a JSTL is. Whatever I search, it redirects to JSTL related articles, which I seldom understand !

```
${applicationVersionNumber}
```

What does this mean ? From where this value is read ? Any help is highly appreciated.

Also I see the below on top of my file. Which one of these three lines is actually required for `${applicationVersionNumber}` to work ?

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/log-1.0" prefix="log"%>
```

Comment: Put your mouse above either of the `[jsp][jstl][el]` tags below the question. In the popbox which shows, click the *info* link.

Comment: Also, what does `<%@` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the taglib is necessary as it is a JSP 2.0 standard.

It just print the content of the variable in the document.

For more details about the EL expressions, this is the documentation you're looking for:  http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref207.html#1010522

Comment: "EL" is short for "Expression Language".  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language

Comment: link broke, now at: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsp-2.1-fr-eval-spec-oth-JSpec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec-el.pdf?AuthParam=1383258611_264a7152411e5b94ec776e7f98e1342b

Comment: Seems like this other link is not accessible anymore!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK From JSP 2.0 the pattern `${ }` is declared that identifies EL expressions. In short EL expressions are enclosed by the `${`  `}` characters.

> ${applicationVersionNumber} What does this mean ?

This will print/refer to value of `applicationVersionNumber`.

> Which one of these three lines is actually required for
>   ${applicationVersionNumber} to work ?

None of them.

Comment: Yes, no taglibs. It's not part of the JSTL but JSP 2.0

Answer (score 2):

The dollar symbol is just for printing the value of the variable. Its just a short cut for a scriplet that prints . It relies on Java Bean specs and it is same as ".get"

One major difference between using $ and scriplet is EL is null safe, whereas scriplets are not.